# Enabling audio output from VMware ubuntu guest to another user X session

Tags: vmware-player, xserver

I've configured my Xhost session under User1 to allow access for User2, then started VMware Player with an Ubuntu guest from User2 suoed command line.  I can see music bar from the virtual machine is playing but I'm unable to hear it in my User1 x session. How can I ensure that audio from the VMware Ubuntu guest is also audible in the User1 session?